# Is it possible to change the line style of component in DM script?

Tags: dm-script

I add a circle component to an image by using NewOvalAnnotation. I know I can adjust the color of this circle. Is it possible to change the line style of this circle from solid to dash line?

Answer (score 0):

No, not with the current software. Annotations do not support such styles. 
All currently available commands to change parameters can be found in the "Component" section of the script help documentation.